# Universal Image Loader: Get ImageView Object From Tap

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, universal-image-loader

After combing through the example project for UIL I have found a snag.

This is what their code shows for the onItemClickListener. I need to return the ImageView object, not null.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return null;
}
```

They don't actually return the item from a position. I can't not override this method but I am completely stuck on how to return the item. I watched the Google I/O talk about ListAdapters (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) and they said do NOT cache a list of images and then return the position based off that (because you will get erratic behaviour when the garbage collector does its stuff).

So can you advise how exactly I get an ImageView object from a UIL ImageAdapater(BaseAdapter) Object?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of UIL. The `adapter` itself handles list of data not a view. So, `getItem` gives about data and its array index (`position` in your code), not a `ImageView` you clicked.

To pass `View` object from the adapter, you need to pass `ImageView` object with Listener at the ViewHolder `OnClick` event.

First, define interface.

```
public interface ViewClickListener {
    void onClickView(View view);
}
```

At the view layout that you inflated, add below code.

```
private ViewClickListener viewClickListener;
public void setViewClickListener(ViewClickListener listener) {
    this.viewClickListener = listener;
}
```

And, in the adapter view,

```
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (viewClickListener!= null)
                viewClickListener.onClickView(view);
        }
    });
```

In the class which contains adapter,

```
public class SomeActivity implements ViewClickListener  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        yourAdapter.setViewClickListener(this); // listens onclick event inside of adapter view.            
    }

    @Override
    onClickView(View view){
          Log.d("Test", view); // your clicked ImageView comes here.
    }
}
```